Laravel Socialite Login Error with Google Sign-In
I am trying to implement socialite into my laravel project where users can login with their google accounts.
Here is my usercontroller file
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function login(){
        return view('auth.user.login');
    }
    
    public function google()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback(){
        return 'provider callback';
        
        $callback = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
        $data = [
            'name' => $callback->getName(),
            'email' => $callback->getEmail(),
            'avatar' => $callback->getAvatar(),
            'email_verified_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()),
        ];

        return $data;
    }

}

and here is my routes for socialite in my web.php file
// socialite routes
Route::get('sign-in-google', [UserController::class, 'google'])->name('user.login.google');
Route::get('auth/google/callback', [UserController::class, 'handleProviderCallback'])->name('user.google.callback');

this is what I always get after trying to login with my google account
enter image description here
I tried rechecking the authorized redirect URLs of my google API and it matches with the one that I put in my env files. Is there something wrong with my coding or does it have to do with my google api?
I'm hoping someone could give me some idea on what to fix here, thanks a lot.

Why are you leaving the method with return 'provider callback';, before it has a chance to do its actual job? Was that supposed to be a debugging measure?

yeah, i just wanted to see if the method works. so yeah you can say that was a debugging measure so that i can see if the message appears after the method does it job.

"so that i can see if the message appears after the method does it job" - but you are not giving it any chance to do its job, by returning immediately.

ohhokay, so i just need to delete the return 'provider callback':?
